# Facebook post login friends list permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-permissions

I've been trying for a while now to find any information regarding the following issue with no success.
I have a player which is already logged in to Facebook and he was never prompted to give friends list permission, is it possible to prompt that request for permission by itself without the entire login sequence to an already logged in user.
I.E. the user logs in to Facebook at a certain point in the application and on a different point I recognise that he is logged in and then I ask for the friends list permission as a stand alone request.

Comment: Yes, you can check the login state using `JS SDK` and if user is logged in call `FB.login` with the scope you want user approval.

Comment: Since this is a new login request only with a different scope, assuming the user declined would he still be logged in to Facebook or would the request dismissal cause a logout to an already logged in user? (forgive my ignorance in the subject I'm rather new to the Facebook SDK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask users for additional permissions at any time, by simply calling the login dialog again.

It will only ask the user for permissions they did not already grant in the past.

And no, if the user declines that specific permission, it will not log them out.